# MessageQueue and Async / Await

Tags: c#, message-queue, async-await

I only want to receive my message in a async method! and its freezing my UI

```
    public async void ProcessMessages()
    {
        MessageQueue MyMessageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\MyTransactionalQueue");
        MyMessageQueue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new Type[] { typeof(string) });

        while (true)
        {
            MessageQueueTransaction MessageQueueTransaction = new MessageQueueTransaction();
            MessageQueueTransaction.Begin();

            ContainError = false;
            ProcessPanel.SetWaiting();

            string Body = MyMessageQueue.Receive(MessageQueueTransaction).Body.ToString();

            //Do some process with body string.

            MessageQueueTransaction.Commit();
        }
    }
```

I am just calling the method like any regular method and its nos working! 
This code used to work when i was using BackgroundWorkers instead of async/await

Ideas?

Comment: Is your code producing any warnings? Did you read what they say and tried to understand them?

Comment: Look in your error list, you'll see "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously"

Comment: This is not a localized question -indeed, there are many similar questions in SO where people think that `async` somehow makes their method run asynchronously

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Stephen writes, async doesn't run your code in a thread. Fortunately, you can use [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) with [MessageQueue.BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.beginreceive.aspx)/MessageQueue.EndReceive to receive messages asynchronously:

```
    private  async Task<Message> MyAsyncReceive()
    {
        MessageQueue queue=new MessageQueue();
        ...
        var message=await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Message>(
                           queue.BeginReceive(),
                           queue.EndReceive);

        return message;

    }
```

You should note though that there ISN'T a version of BeginReceive that uses a Transaction. From BeginReceive's docs:

> Do not use the asynchronous call BeginReceive with transactions. If you want to perform a transactional asynchronous operation, call BeginPeek, and put the transaction and the (synchronous) Receive method within the event handler you create for the peek operation.

This makes sense as there is no guarantee how long you have to wait for a response or which thread will eventually handle the completed call.

To use transactions you would write something like this:

```
    private  async Task<Message> MyAsyncReceive()
    {
        var queue=new MessageQueue();

        var message=await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Message>(queue.BeginPeek(),queue.EndPeek);

        using (var tx = new MessageQueueTransaction())
        {
            tx.Begin();

            //Someone may have taken the last message, don't wait forever
            //Use a smaller timeout if the queue is local
            message=queue.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), tx);
            //Process the results inside a transaction
            tx.Commit();
        }
        return message;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

As Rob pointed out, the original code used the `message` returned from `Peek`, which may have changed between `Peek` and `Receive`. In this case the second message will be lost.

There's still a chance of blocking though, if another client reads the last message in the queue. To prevent this, `Receive` should have a small timeout.

Comment: This answer is great! and it works!
If I want to run this MyAsyncReceive method multiple times they will share my thread? So they will be slow?

Comment: There is nothing special about the method. The runtime will use an available thread from the threadpool for each invocation.

Comment: Doesn't this contain a race-condition? The `message` variable may contain a different message than the one received, doesn't it? (Especially if there are more than one consumers). The peek will return *a* message but the `Receive()` method may receive a different one. I would drop the `var message = ` in the 'Peek awaiter' and use `var message = queue.Receive(tx);` to make sure the correct message is processed in the transaction..

Comment: Oops, should be `message=queue.Receive(tx)`.

Comment: It's not enough to use the received message, as someone else may have received the only available message. Either `Receive` should have a very short timeout, or a cursor should be used to ensure the peeked message is actually loaded

Comment: What benefits exactly does the transaction give over the first example?

Comment: @user1713059 transactions are an essential part of queue processing. The entire model is based on the assumption that if something goes wrong, eg if the queue handler dies, the message is placed back in the queue. Good messages are reprocessed eventually. Bad messages end up in the dead letter queue. Cloud providers replace transactions with leasing which is more scaleable but leads to slow retries

Answer (score 6):

[`async` does not run your code on a background thread.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx#6) Your code above should have caused a compiler warning that tells you that your method will run synchronously.

If you want to execute a method on a background thread, use `TaskEx.Run`:

```
public void ProcessMessages()
{
  ...
}

TaskEx.Run(() => ProcessMessages());
```

Comment: If I use run so it will créate a new thread! so I cant modify the UI Directly, i will need to use Dispatch rigth? like ordinary threads? Or is there any other way? I just need to update a progress bar that is in the Main Form.

Comment: I recommend using `IProgress<T>` and `Progress<T>` which handles the thread dispatching for you. The [TAP documentation covers `IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: I can't mark two answers as right! The answer of my question is using Task.Factory.FromAsync but that way i will not use the power of new threads. So I will use Run! Thanks