# Is there no Async implementation of MSMQ send in .net 4.5

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, .net-4.5, msmq

I wonder why there is no async implementation of MSMQ send? I am using .net 4.5. Am I missing something?

Comment: But see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16104783/613130

Comment: Why do you want an asynchronous `Send` method? Sending something to a queue shouldn't take so much time that an asynchronous Send is needed. Are you trying to send something to a remote queue? Have you encountered a specific problem or are you trying to avoid blocking in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need for an asynchronous version of `Send` because `Send` is asynchronous.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711381(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Sending messages in Message Queuing is always an asynchronous
>   operation. When you are sure the queue is open, you can continue to
>   send messages without stopping to wait for a reply.

Even [for remote queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703235(v=vs.85).aspx)

> When a message is sent to an opened queue on a remote computer, Message > Queuing stores the message in an outgoing queue on the local computer.

Are you having a specific performance problem or did you want to use an async method just in case `Send` caused blocking?

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect, Send is blocking although it is only writing to a local queue.

Invoke `await Task.Yield();` just before any call to `MessageQueue.Send(..)`.

This will have a considerable impact in throughput if you purely use async/await.